# scrapy python re statement

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, scrapy

I am learning about scrapy. I am using scrapy 0.20 that is why I am following this tutorial. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.20/intro/tutorial.html

I undrstood the concepts. However, I have one thing yet.

In this statement

```
sel.xpath('//title/text()').re('(\w+):')
```

the output is

```
[u'Computers', u'Programming', u'Languages', u'Python']
```

what is **re('(\w+):')** using for please?

#### to help answering:

this statement

```
sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
```

has this output:

```
[u'Open Directory - Computers: Programming: Languages: Python: Books']
```

why is the comma `,` added between the elements?
Also, all the ':' are removed.

Moreover: is this a python pure syntax please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regular expression (regex), and is a whole world unto itself.

**(\w+):** Will return any text that ends in a colon (but does not return the colon)
[Here is an example of how it works with the ":" getting removed](http://regex101.com/r/lF6qC2)

**(\w+:)** Will return any text that ends in a colon (and will also return the colon) 
[Here is an example of how it works with the ":" staying in](http://regex101.com/r/sD5pY4)

Also, if you want to learn about regex, Codecademy has a good [python course](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-advanced-en-7hJDu/0/1)

Comment: Thank you very much. I accept your answer, but please do u know why always there is a `u` ?? :)

Comment: That means that it is a unicode string (see: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
(\w+):
```

is a Regular Expression, which matches any word which ends with `:` and groups all the word characters (`[a-zA-Z_]`).

The output does not have `:`, because this method returns all the captured groups.

The results are returned as a Python list. When a list is represented as a string, the elements are separated by `,`.

`\w` is a shortform for `[a-zA-Z_]`

Quoting from [Python Regular Expressions Page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html),

> \w
>
> When the LOCALE and UNICODE flags are not specified, matches any
>   alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the
>   set [a-zA-Z0-9_]. With LOCALE, it will match the set [0-9_] plus
>   whatever characters are defined as alphanumeric for the current
>   locale. If UNICODE is set, this will match the characters [0-9_] plus
>   whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character
>   properties database.

Comment: OK, i understand all what you said. except why ":" is removed?can u explain please?

Comment: The ":" is removed because the regex only returns the matches inside of the brackets. Now it is (\w+): BUT if it was (\w+:) instead then the ":" would not be removed. See my answer for an example with this.